# In matlab, how to increase the dimension of a matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A=(1 2; 3 4)`, and I want to augment `A` to `B = (1 2 0; 3 4 0; 0 0 0)`, what can I do ?

One way is: `B = [[A, zeros(2,1)]; zeros(1,3)]`

But it might be clumsy in a dynamic process, any other ideas ?

Answer (score 5):

```
B=A
B(3,3)=0
```

Matlab fills the other elements automatically with zeros

Comment: To make it more generic: `A(end+1,end+1) = 0`

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
padarray(A,[1 1],'post')
```

Output:

```
ans =

     1     2     0
     3     4     0
     0     0     0
```

It's a little more versatile and makes the semantics very clear.